# SPRING BOOT: Application failed to start after migrating to Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3

I am having a maven `v-3.6.3` multi-module spring-boot `v-2.1.6.RELEASE` application. Recently I migrated from Java 8 to Java 11 and I am getting the following error in the logs. Can someone help me to understand the issue? What causes this error in `Java 11`:

```
    ERROR  - java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger - Error loading factory org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteJdbc41Factory
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.definePackage(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.definePackageIfNecessary(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.instantiateFactory(UnregisteredDriver.java:115)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.createFactory(UnregisteredDriver.java:74)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.<init>(UnregisteredDriver.java:55)
    at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver.<init>(Driver.java:60)
    at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:614)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.ensureDriversInitialized(DriverManager.java:594)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:424)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:689)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(SybDriver.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is a bug in the Sybase JDBC driver, it should unconditionally register itself with `DriverManager`, but instead it first tries to see if it was already registered before registering itself, which triggers this stack overflow because automatic driver loading tries to load the driver, which triggers the registration, which checks if it is already registered, etc.... However, I would expect this to occur irrespective of the Java version. Check if upgrading your Sybase driver version might fix this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank You so much. I will upgrade the JDBC driver and let you know.